# Configuring angularjs with eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, angularjs

I want to start using AngularJs and Java Spring for development purpose.I am using Eclipse as IDE . I want to configure my Eclipse to have these frameworks working seamlessly.

I know I may be asking too much,but trust me I have done much research on my part and you guys are my last resort.Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You'd first wanna make sure you have the [**JSDT**](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/) installed.

Next thing is to install some dedicated tools for the job, so check out [AngularJS Eclipse Tools](https://github.com/sbegaudeau/AngularJS-Eclipse-Tools). The [AngularJS Eclipse Templates](https://github.com/bkbonner/angularjs-eclipse-templates) might be of help, too, and here's a [visual guide written for it](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/visual-guide-templates-eclipse) to get you started.

Also see the [AngularJS Eclipse getting started page](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started).

---

*Since this answer had been posted, the [AngularJS Eclipse plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angularjs-eclipse) was released, as other answers stated. You might wanna check it out first.*

Comment: Thanks a lot..I'll surely check as it looks promising.

Comment: "which is not optimal IMO for JavaScript developers", so can you suggest a more appropriate tool ? (preferably free ;))

Comment: @Chafik, i use intellij's [*idea*](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), but only because i also develop in java - [*webstorm*](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) is practically the same, but web oriented (*webstorm* has a subset of *idea*'s capabilities). *idea* has a community edition, but it lacks the web features, and both can be obtained for free for one month evaluation period. anyhow i think they worth the money if you decide to get the commercial version.

Answer (score 33):

- Install **[JavaScript Development Tools (JSDT)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/)** and [**AngularJS Eclipse**](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angularjs-eclipse#.VCmjT9WUeZU) plug-in in eclipse from **Eclipse Marketplace** or Update site [**angularjs-eclipse-0.5.0**](http://oss.opensagres.fr/angularjs-eclipse/0.5.0/),
  [image: Install AngularJS Eclipse]
- **`Right Click on your project --> Configure --> Convert to Angularjs Project`** (as shown below)
  [image: Convert Angularjs Project]

> Now you can see the Angularjs tags available as shown below.

[image: AngularJS Tags are available].

Comment: I installed this plug-in but the option "Convert to AngularJS Project" don't appear.

Comment: @Krismorte same here. Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure the project is extracted on your hard disk.
2. In Eclipse go to the menu: File->New->Project.
3. Select "General->Project" and click on the next button.
4. Enter the project name in the  "Project name:"  field
5. Disable "Use default location" Click on the "Browse ..." button    and select the folder that contains the project (the one from step 1)
6. Click on the "Finish" button
7. Right-click with the mouse on you're new    project and click "Configure->Convert to AngularJS Project.."
8. Enable    you're project goodies and click on the "OK" button.

Comment: How can i convert that project into war file after that.

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans 8.0 (beta at the time of this post) has Angular support as well as HTML5 support.

Check out this Oracle article: https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/integrated_angularjs_development

Answer (score 1):

Since these previous answers above, there is now a release of an Eclipse Plugin to assist with development using AngularJS:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angularjs-eclipse
https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Installation---Update-Site  (take a look around the other Wiki pages for information on features)

The release at the time of the answer is 0.1.0.

Please also checkout JSDT (http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/) and also Eclipse VJET (http://eclipse.org/vjet/).  The VJET project appears to be an attempt to provide better feature sets to the editor without being encumbered by the JSDT project (open source politics at play I guess).

Answer (score 1):

Download angular js from this link and add as new software in eclipse
http://oss.opensagres.fr/angularjs-eclipse/0.6.0/

Answer (score 0):

Configuration worked with Eclipse Mars 4.5 version.

1) Install Eclipse Mars 4.5 from 
https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/mars2
This comes with Tern and embedded Node.js server

2) Install AngularJS Eclipse plugin from Eclipse Marketplace

3) Configure node.js server to the embedded nodejs server within Eclipse (found in the eclipse plugins folder) at Windows-> Preferences -> JavaScript -> Tern -> Server -> node.js. No extra configurations are required.

4) Test configuration in a html or javascript file. 
https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

With current Angular 4 and 5 versions, there is an IDE for that.

Go to eclipse market place any search for 'Angular'. You will see the IDE and install it.

[image]

After that restart eclipse and follow the welcome messages to choose preferences.

How to start using eclipse with angular projects?

Considering you already have angular project and you want to import it into eclipse.

go to `file > import > choose Angular Project`

[image]

and It would be better to have your projects in a separate working set so that you will not confuse it with other kind of (like java)projects.

With Angular IDE  You will have a terminal window too.

To open this type terminal in  eclipse search box(quick access) on the top right corner.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Hi Guys if u are using angular plugin in eclipse that time is plugin is limited periods after that if u want to used this plugin then u pay it so i suggest to you used webstrome and visual code ide that are very easy and comfort to used so take care if u start and developed a angular app using eclipse

Comment: How does this solve the problem? After all, please edit the formatting of your answer

Comment: Hi Nico haase if u have a problem then switch to webstrome or visual basic beacuse eclipse plugin is paid!

Comment: I have exactly no problem, espescially not with a tool that takes a one-time fee of $49 (in terms of Angular IDE). AngularJS Eclipse is a free plugin, and WebStorm costs at least $35 a month.