# Plugins of AngularJs for eclipse juno

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, angularjs

I am working with angular js in my eclipse ide but i could not find good angularjs plugis for eclipse.
I went through  https://github.com/sbegaudeau/AngularJS-Eclipse-Tools and it was not giving me proper instructions to install the plugin.
Is there any other plugins to work with angularjs in eclipse ide. I worked with jsdt also which is only suitable to javascript but not for angulrjs.

Comment: Seems on the github they don't include the jar's for the plugin. Looks like you need to pull the project and build it yourself to install it.

Answer (score 6):

Or maybe you could use this plugin : https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Well, unfortunately not much has changed since these questions - so I don't want to repeat what is written there but just the advice to read it there (esp. the second one):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989859/what-is-the-best-ide-for-angularjs

and

[Configuring angularjs with eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421523/configuring-angularjs-with-eclipse-ide)

Personally I would say: Use Webstorm/IDEA, it is so much better for HTML/CSS/JS-development in general :-)

Answer (score 1):

- Use [**AngularJS Eclipse 0.5.0**](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angularjs-eclipse#.VCmjT9WUeZU) plug-in from **Eclipse Marketplace**,
  [image: Install AngularJS Eclipse]
- Then **`Right Click on your Project --> Configure --> Convert to Angularjs Project`** 
  [image: Convert Angularjs Project]

> Now you can see the Angularjs tags in Eclipse Editor.

[image: AngularJS Tags are available].