# How to minfiy Javascript files in the Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a project using AngularJS and I am planning to minfiy the JS and CSS files in Eclipse IDE.

I am very new to Eclipse. Could you please suggest some process and links.

Comment: please check this link i hope you will get idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269560/javascript-editor-plugin-for-eclipse

Comment: Hi @Nazmul Hasan, it is not helping what ever you shared link. Do you have any other suggestions. Thanks in advance

Comment: do you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421523/configuring-angularjs-with-eclipse-ide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would integrate a minify step in your build process rather than (manually) minifying the Javascript code after each change.
Which tool is best suited depends on how you build the software.

You may also want to consider to let your server minify Javascript code on the fly before delivering. That again depends on the server that delivers your resources - if that is under your control.

For ocassionally minifying Javascript code, there are several Eclipse plug-ins that claim to to the job:

- [YUICompressor Eclipse integration](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/yuicompressor)
- [JSMin Eclipse Plug-in](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsminplugin/)
- [JSCompressor](https://github.com/oncereply/jscompressor)

... or you can resort to an online service like http://jscompress.com/.

Comment: https://jscompress.com/ does not support async function and syntax like new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)