# How to resolve problem with Wild Web Developer install

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, wildwebdeveloper

I need a plugin for Angular in Eclipse.  I'd like to run and debug 'ng serve' in Eclipse and be able to edit and existing Angular project that has been created elsewhere (in a MS Visual Studio tool I've been told).  I'm looking into using Wild Web Developer as I can't find any real documentation on how to do this in Eclipse with [AngularIDE](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular-ide).  There is some documentation for AngularJS linked to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421523/configuring-angularjs-with-eclipse-ide) but the [install](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angularjs-eclipse-outdated-use-wild-web-developer-instead) says it has been replaced by Wild Web Developer (I'm open to the suggestion of other plugin options).

I'm having trouble installing Wild Web Developer.

When I drag the [install](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/wild-web-developer-html-css-javascript-typescript-nodejs-angular-json-yaml-kubernetes-xml) into my running instance of Eclipse it just opens up the Eclipse Market Place window.

If I search for Wild Web Developer I get ~700 responses and I don't see Wild Web Developer there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the version of Eclipse I'm running:

[image]

EDIT:
I get the same behavior with this version of Eclipse:
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Those look like the same *version*, from early 2018. Wild Web Developer *really* wants you to be on the current release, which is 2020-03, for it to be installed. After all, you're not writing against 2 year old versions of node and Angular, are you?

Add https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest to your Available Sites preference page, and check for updates.